# Being Informed when a Vuex mutation happens

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I would like to avoid using event bus to being informed when a value in state placed. is there any event when a **mutation** called? I think it exists since it's event showing in Vue dev tools.

Comment: I suppose Vue dev tools just uses  a state props reactivity to know about changes. You also can a watch on a certain prop in state to track changes,

Comment: Can't you just use the `mapState` functions to map the variable you want to monitor to your component as computed value, and put a watcher on that value?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman it's posible but i think it could be too much redundant code if i want to have multiple mutation listener in a component. if it was a simple event for each mutation would be nice